# Multitenant authentication for .NET CORE API

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, multi-tenant

What is the easiest way to achieve this? I have secured API and requests which come to it have access tokens. These tokens are generated once by Azure B2C in **TENANT-A** and other time by  Azure B2C in **TENANT-B**. I want to let them in only if configuration for these two tenants exist in my appsettings.json

Comment: Do you mean let them in when the tenants are from A and B? You can check this [link](https://squarewidget.com/asp-net-core-multi-tenant-api/) first

Comment: @Tisa it is not for authentication. I want to let in, requests with token generated by different Azure ad b2c